# npm install @vue/cli doesnt work it gives error

Tags: vue.js

it give this error/
vue : File C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

```
npm install @vue/cli
```

Comment: calling for all the professionals here! hehe

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Answer (score -2):

this is a problem in windows powershell but if you use gitbash. it will work. however if you want to use powershell.
put this in the terminal without using it as an administrator.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```